# center an image on a top of an image

Tags: html, css

I want to put the play button (first img) centered to the second images. I can do it with position absolute and margin but how can that be dynamic? What if I'm in a loop and the height of the second images is not always the same?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yusuuqck/

```
<div>
    <img class="ply" src="http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png"/>
<img src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do that using img, you must use a div in the background image, fix the width and height of the div or of the image, images un html are not blocks and can be expanded more than divs, look this http://jsfiddle.net/L51auybr/

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the second image like a background and the containing div dislpayed as flex, and the play button with margin auto. So, that button always be centered in the box.

Here better explained:

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
<div class="bg_img">
    <img src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

css

```
.bg_img { position: relative; }

.bg_img span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url(http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div display as table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/yusuuqck/2/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img class="ply" src="http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png"/>
    <img src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.ply{
   position:absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   margin-top: -25px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -25px; /* Half the width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    img{
       width:100%; 
       height:auto; 
    }
}

.ply{
   position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   margin-top: -25px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -25px; /* Half the width */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="ply" src="http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png"/>
<img src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg"/>
</div>
```